# Clocked SR latch VHDL

Tags: integrated-circuit, vhdl

i am trying to build a clocked SR latch using 4xNAND gates
When i reset the the SR latch, the output should be 0, buts its still '1' and output complement is oscillating, we all know VHDL is a poor language can anyone help?

[image]

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;

--Clocked SR latch, 4 x NAND logic configuration

--Declare clocked SR_Latch entity
entity clocked_SRLatch is
    port(
        clk : in std_logic;
        set : in std_logic;
        reset : in std_logic;
        output : out std_logic;
        outputComp : out std_logic
        
    );
end clocked_SRLatch;

architecture behavioural of clocked_SRLatch is

    signal feedback_out : std_logic := '1';
    signal feedback_outcomp : std_logic := '0';


begin

    
    
    process(clk, reset, set) begin
            output <= feedback_out;
            outputComp <= feedback_outcomp;
            outputComp <= (reset NAND clk) NAND feedback_out;
            output <= (set NAND clk) NAND feedback_outcomp;
    end process;
    
end behavioural;

TESTBENCH
library IEEE;
use IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;


entity clocked_SRLatch_tb is
end clocked_SRLatch_tb;

architecture behavioural of clocked_SRLatch_tb is
    component clocked_SRLatch 
            port(
                clk : in std_logic;
                set : in std_logic;
                reset : in std_logic;
                output : out std_logic;
                outputComp : out std_logic
        
            );
    end component;

    constant clock_period: time := 1 ns;
    signal stop_the_clock: boolean;
    signal clk: std_logic;
    signal set: std_logic;
    signal reset: std_logic;
    signal output: std_logic;
    signal outputComp: std_logic;

begin

    clocked_sr_i : clocked_SRLatch port map (clk=>clk,set=>set,reset=>reset,output=>output,outputComp=>outputComp);

    clocking : process begin
      while not stop_the_clock loop
          clk <= '0', '1' after clock_period / 2;
          wait for clock_period;
      end loop;
    wait;
    end process;

    stimulus : process begin
        set <= '0';
        reset <= '0';
        wait for 5 ns;
        reset <= '1';
        assert false report "End of testbench";
        wait;
    end process;

end behavioural;
```

Comment: Why are you assigning signals "output" and "outputComp" twice in the process!!! It doesn't work this way!

Comment: Because i have to connect the signals to the output ports and in VHDL you apparently cannot drive an input port with an output port

Comment: How do i connect an output port to an input port without an internal architecture signal?

Comment: I meant why you assign a signal twice. you  have assigned the "output" signal two times in a raw without any if-condition in the process. The same u did for "outputComp"

Comment: Okay i understand the statements are executed sequentially, how do i connect a signal to the output entity port and then connect to input port?

Comment: Try learning about "buffer" and "inout" attribution to the in/out ports. For example if u use "buffer" instead of "out" in the definition of a port u can use it inward into your circuit.

Comment: By the way, if ur circuit is going to be a bunch of Gates without any flip-flop, then u wouldn't need a process. because ur circuit is combinational

Comment: Another point, VHDL is a powerfull language to implement digital circuits. But note that u have to think in a "hardware" way not in a "software" language like C and Java.

Comment: I've been using VHDL since the 1990s and still don't know it's a poor language. Learn it properly and you might find otherwise.

Comment: instead of blaming the language blame yourself, your code obviously shows that you don't have any knowledge on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> we all know VHDL is a poor language

Why is VHDL a poor language?

```
outputComp <= feedback_outcomp;
outputComp <= (reset NAND clk) NAND feedback_out;
```

The second line is superseeding the first, means

```
outputComp <= feedback_outcomp;
```

has no effect.
And the same problem you have with the `output`

```
output <= feedback_out;
output <= (set NAND clk) NAND feedback_outcomp;
```

I would generally embed it into a clocked process, it makes the whole implementation more readable and more predictable.

So you need the following structure?

[image]

You should be able to read from outputs when using the VHDL2008 standard, previous standards did not support this feature what would require two additional internal signals.

```
signal s_n, r_n : std_logic;

s_n <= set NAND clk;
r_n <= reset NAND clk;
output <= s_n NAND outputcomp;
outputcomp <= s_r NAND output;
```

Comment: The SR latch is clocked or gated and is active High, you need 4 NAND gates
How do i use an output port to drive an input port?
I only did that because it was said that i must create an internal architecture signal and connect it to the output port before driving the input port

Comment: But is the architecture shown in my answer what you want to achieve?

Comment: No its missing 2 NAND gates at the front which both connect to a clock and each have S and R

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: You might also mention the sensitivity list surprises in that first process.

Comment: As it's fully combinatorial a process doesn't make much sense at all

Comment: Thank you how do i use VHDL2008 standard?

Comment: clockedsr.vhd:42:27: port "outputcomp" cannot be read
clockedsr.vhd:43:22: no declaration for "s_r"

Comment: By telling your simulator/synthesizer

Comment: Im using GHDL compiler and GTKwave simulator any ideas?

Comment: GHDL has a `--std=08` flag, `ghdl -a --std=08 {your file}`. The declaration for `s_r` is in my code snipped

Comment: THank you buddy, how long have you been designing hardware?

Comment: I generally do not design hardware, I just describe it... using the poor language VHDL :)

Comment: Well i only said that because there doesn't seem to be too large a support community for it in comparison to software languages :D

Comment: And also isnt something you can solve using logic either, so its fustration :/

Comment: Agreed with the comparably small community but the logic is pretty simple, given the small syntax set. But it takes some time to get a sense for it when coming from regular sequential programming

Comment: Dude the example didnt work, i get uninitialized values for the simulation any ideas?
On set and reset they are unitiliased

Comment: Update the code you have